# Problem when retrieving uploaded file with Firebase Storage using Redux Saga

Tags: firebase, redux, firebase-storage, redux-saga

I'm using `redux saga` with `firebase` in an app. When I need to use the firebase storage and I need to get the download URL of a file I just upload:

this doesn't work

`yield call (uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL);`

but this work

`yield call (() => uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());`

can anyone help me understand why the first option isn't working? I didn't understand the difference between these approaches :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between those is what value `this` has once getDownloadURL is running. The first version will have `this` equal to the window object (in non-strict mode) or undefined (in strict mode), while the latter will have `this` equal to `uploadTask.snapshot.ref`.

The `call` effect does have a couple of overloads which let you specify `this`. You can see them [listed here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args), but one example is to pass in an array as the first argument, as in:

```
yield call([uploadTask.snapshot.ref, uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL])
```